# Knockout containerless control flow syntax not executing data bindings

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to use Knockout's containerless control flow syntax without much luck. Well, the actual control flow is working, but child HTML elements are not getting bound.

I have a simple object:

```
function Person(name, vegetarian) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.vegetarian= vegetarian;
}
```

And I want a list of all people, with a link to the Vegetarian society if they are vegetarian.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
<li>
        <!-- ko if: vegetarian() -->
        <a href="http://www.vegsoc.org">
        <!-- /ko -->
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <!-- ko if: vegetarian() -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mxmS9/

**Why are my 2 people not getting displayed in the list?**

Delete the ko comments and you will at least see that the `foreach` is working correctly.

I am using the containerless control flow syntax because in my actual project, there is a lot more HTML than the simple `<span>` in this example, and I do not want to repeat it.

Knockout v2.3.0

Comment: As a vegetarian i can tell you that `vegatarian` is not a `function`, just a `boolean`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use the containerless control flow syntax this way, because you cannot break up a n element's open/closing tags with them.

What you need to do is to repeat the common content:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        <!-- ko if: vegetarian -->
        <a href="http://www.vegsoc.org"><span data-bind="text: name"></span></a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: vegetarian -->
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or if you have more content what you don't want to repeat move it to a template:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        <!-- ko if: vegetarian -->
        <a href="http://www.vegsoc.org" data-bind="template: 'linkTemplate'"></a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: vegetarian -->
            <!-- ko template: 'linkTemplate'--><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/html" id="linkTemplate">
  <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</script>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaL9R/).

Comment: I do not want to repeat the common content (your first example), because my content is complex. But your second example looks very promising.